# What is the difference between representation and basis in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, terminology

Actually I am confused with the word "representation/basis " of an operator and wavefunctions?

Comment: Can you give an example of how those words are being used in some text? The answer depends heavily on context.

Answer (score 6):

The basis of a vector space is a linearly independent set of elements such that their linear combinations are dense in the space. The representation of an operator onto a given basis is the set of expectation values of that operator onto the given basis, namely its matrix elements.

Given $\left\{a\right\}$ as a basis of $V$, the representation of an operator $\hat{A}$ onto $\left\{a\right\}$ is
$$
\langle a |\hat{A}|a'\rangle = (\hat{A})^a_{a'}.
$$

In quantum mechanics, given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ equipped with the position basis vectors$^1$ $|x\rangle$, the wave function of a state $|\psi\rangle$ is the scalar product $\psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle$. Likewise, the representation of an operator acting on a state onto a given basis is, for example:
$$
\langle x |\hat{p}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x)
$$

---

$^1$ The $|x\rangle$ are not really vectors in the proper sense, but that is another matter.

Comment: Also, the word "representation" may refer to the Hilbert space representation of the canonical commutation relations. In this sense it is analogous to "quantization", however, in some cases it is not at all straightforward and does not resemble canonical quantization.

Comment: Very true, I agree.